# Issue with using searchbar

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar

I am trying to implement a search functionality in one of my screens. This is the code that is posted...

```
func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchActive = true;
}
func searchBarTextDidEndEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchActive = false;
}
func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchActive = false;
}
func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchActive = false;
}
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

    if searchText != "" {
        // Filter the results
        searchActive = true
//allTheData is an object of an array of struct
        filtered = self.allTheData.filter { _ in (searchText.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())) }


        if(filtered.count == 0){
            searchActive = false;
        } else {
            searchActive = true;
        }
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }}
```

The code in `cellForRow` is given as:

```
    if(searchActive){

        let filtObj = filtered[indexPath.row]

        cell.nameLabel.text = filtObj.customer_name
        cell.amtLabel.text = "\(filtObj.total_sales)"
    } else {
        let dataObj = allTheData[indexPath.row]
        cell.nameLabel.text = dataObj.customer_name
        cell.amtLabel.text = "\(dataObj.total_sales)"
    }
```

And the code in `numberOfRows` is given as:

```
 if(searchActive) {
            return filtered.count
        }

        return allTheData.count
```

But the search is not happening. Don't know what is the reason. Hope somebody can help...

Comment: have you connected the UISearchBar delegate to your view controller?

Comment: you mean from the storyboard or in code...?

Comment: Give an outlet connection of your searchBar. And just put this in your viewDidLoad - yourSearchBarOutletName.delegate = self .
Also you can directly connect the delegate from storyboard to viewController

Comment: yes...even that has been tried...

Comment: Please rephrase your title. Currently it's almost as bad as saying "I have a question"

Comment: Thanks @Thomas Tempelmann for the suggestion...

Answer (score 0):

Your filter logic is wrong

```
filtered = self.allTheData.filter { $0.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased()) }
```

Comment: Ok...I tried it...but it gives an error saying my struct type has no member `contains`...

Comment: trying `filtered = self.allTheData.filter { $0.customer_name.contains(searchText.lowercased()) }` gives some search results now. But the results are improper...

Comment: This made it work...` filtered = self.allTheData.filter({( data : CustomerData) -> Bool in
                return data.customer_name.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())
            })`

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't know allTheData was a struct. I thought it was an array. Anyway, glad that you got the point